# Regex and lookahead : java

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds, punctuation

I'm trying to remove punctuation **except** dots (to keep the sentence structure) from a String with regex
Actually, i have no clue how it's working, i just code this :

```
public static String removePunctuation(String s){       
s = s.replaceAll("(?!.)\\p{Punct}" , " ");      
return s;
}
```

I found that we could use "negative lookahead" for this kind of problem, but when i run this code, it doesn't erase anything. The negative lookahead cancelled the \p{Punct} regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.` character has special meaning in regular expressions. It essentially means 'any character except new lines' (unless the `DOTALL` flag is specified, in which case it means 'any character'), so your pattern will match 'any punctuation character that is a new line character—in other words, it never match anything.

If you want it to mean a literal `.` character, you need to escape it like this:

```
s = s.replaceAll("(?!\\.)\\p{Punct}" , " ");
```

Or wrap it in a character class, like this:

```
s = s.replaceAll("(?![.])\\p{Punct}" , " ");
```

Answer (score 3):

The unescaped dot matches *anything* (except newlines). You need at least

```
s = s.replaceAll("(?!\\.)\\p{Punct}" , " ");
```

but for that sort of thing I'd much rather use a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) (within which the dot is no longer a metacharacter and therefore doesn't need to be escaped):

```
s = s.replaceAll("[^\\P{Punct}.]" , " ");
```

**Explanation:**

- `[^abc]` matches any character that's not an `a`, `b`, or `c`.
- `[^\P{Punct}]` matches any character that's "not a not a" punctuation character, effectively matching identically to `\p{Punct}`.
- `[^\P{Punct}.]` therefore matches any character that's a punctuation character *except* a dot.

Comment: +1 for the `[^\\P{Punct}.]`. I forgot that you could negate `\p` like that.